# webSocket "onsend" event?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

In a HTML page in JavaScript using io.connect() is there a way to catch any "onsend" events?

I use a lot of "socket.send()" in different places and I would need to "categorize" and log them and if I could catch them in something like an "onsend" event (like the socket.on("message") when I receive something)...

I do of course realize I can do this in a global function but as the solution is coded the way it is it would require a lot of recoding to do that and retesting is not an option...

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is searching for answer, I will post a workaround I am using, might not work in all cases:

```
let socket = new WebSocket(wsUrl)
let original = socket.send
socket.send = (...args) => {
  doSomethingOnSend()
  return original.apply(socket, args)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the socket.io's default events to send and receive message.

That means if you send a message from server to client, you use

```
//On server side or server side
socket.send(someMessage);

//On another opposite side
socket.on("message", function(data){console.log(data);})
```

The above one kind of event is built-in defined in socket.io libraries. That is somewhere in their code like as

```
//On server side or client side
socket.send = socket.emit("message", someMessage);

//On opposite side
socket.on("message", function(data){console.log(data);})
```

So, In this way, I always define my custom events such as

```
//register a custom events on socket using socket.on function
socket.on("clientSentAData", function(data){console.log(data);})

//Client knows that there is a kind of evnets known as "clientSentAData" in the server side
//So client emit an data using "clientSentAData" event.
socket.emit("clientSentAData", data);
```

I this way I also categorize my bla bla kind of messages/notifications/data.

More specific example

```
//Server code
//Server register the sendMeMusicFile event
socket.on("sendMeMusicFile", function(tileName){
    console.log("Received client request file with title " + tileName);

    socket.emit("takeYourMusicFile", theMusicFile);
    console.log("Sent music file with title " + tileName);
    });



//Client Code 
//Ask for a music
socket.emit("sendMeMusicFile", "Just Give me a reason");

//Client register the takeYourMusicFile event
socket.on("takeYourMusicFile", function(theMusicFile){
    console.log("Received music file with title " + theMusicFile.tile);
        // player.play(theMusicFile)
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but not really what I was looking for...
I need something like socket.onsend() or rather socket.beforesend(). I need to re-route some of the requests because of new servers so I wanted to do that in one place only to not have to change code multiple times in multiple places...